# Bixby Capsule does not launch on phone

Tags: bixby

I have a capsule that I want to test on my Samsung S9+, and have enabled developer options, and created a submission.

However, when I attempt to launch on the phone, I get "Oh, there was a connection problem. Try again later"

How can I figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a reported issue in the latest version of Bixby.  It is being addressed.

https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023521654-Bixby-client-2-1-17-10-breaks-on-device-testing

- issues should be resolved as of 5/31/2019

Comment: Please check for the latest Bixby update.  Version 2.1.18.4 seems to have resolved the "Oh, there was a connection problem.." error, and I was able to interact with a private capsule submission.

Answer (score 0):

I got this email from the development team a few days ago. I guess we should just sit tight.

> Hello Bixby Developers,
>
> On the latest version of the Bixby client (2.1.17.10), if you are
>   using private submissions for on-device testing, there is currently an
>   issue that causes Bixby to fail with an error: "Oh there was a
>   connection problem.  Please try again later"
>
> Our engineering teams are working hard to release a hotfix as soon as
>   possible. We will provide a final email update once this issue is
>   resolved. In the meantime, we will provide ad-hoc updates here.
>
> Thanks, The Bixby Team